# Need to determine if a user in ActiveDirectory is still valid/active

Tags: validation, active-directory

I have a .NET MVC (1.0) application that is using the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to authenticate users, and this is working fine as is.  After a successful authentication, I am creating a custom profile in SQL for that user (AD username, email, etc).

In one part of the application I am sending email alerts to users, and I am looping though users from the local SQL table that holds the AD UserName, mentioned above.  Prior to sending the alert, I would like to verify that the user we are sending to is still a valid (i.e. active) user in AD.  How can I check this without the password of the current user in my loop?

I was hoping to do soemthing like this...

```
MembershipUser adUser= Membership.GetUser(userName); //I have the username from the loop
bool isValid = adUser.isValid; //I know this is not a real property
```

I know that there is no such property called "isValid" -- but does anyone know what property I should use?  If MembershipUser is of no use, then I assume that I need to write some code invoking the System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace?  If so, what property should I be checking in AD to see if the user is valid?  And by "valid," I mean that the user still works for the company in question, and is able to sign-in via AD.  I am not concerned with the user's group membership in AD.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to check the user's `userAccountControl` flag for the `disabled` flag.

Once you have your `DirectoryEntry` for the user in question (userAccount), you can check for account disabled and account locked out like this:

```
// get the "userAccountControl" property
int uac = Convert.ToInt32(userAccount.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]);

const int ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x00000002;
const int ADS_UF_LOCKOUT = 0x00000010;

bool accountIsDisabled = (uac & ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) == ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;
bool accountIsLockedOut = (uac & ADS_UF_LOCKOUT) == ADS_UF_LOCKOUT;
```

Marc

Answer (score 0):

If you query the user attributes/properties in AD, the userAccountControl property will be 514 if the account is locked out or 512 if it is ready for login.

Took to long to post my response.  The post by Marc is actually more detailed, and I will upvote it.